# Passing a variable to python using Ajax method

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I want to pass a variable using Ajax from a JS function to a python function in my Django project.
I am able to call the python function. Using the ajax method, I know this because the print function in the python function runs.
However how to I pass my variable through this ajax call? I just want to pass the local variable so it can be printed by the python function.

**JS**

```
function calling (){
    var local = 25
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'printsome/',
        success: function(response){
            console.log('success');
            console.log(local);
        },
        error: function (response){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

}
```

**python**

```
def print_some(request):
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    print('this python function was called')
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Comment: How is this question related to Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can pass the variable as a queryparameter:

```
function calling (){
    var local = 25
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:`printsome/?variable=${local}`, // <- Add the queryparameter here
        success: function(response){
            console.log('success');
            console.log(local);
        },
        error: function (response){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

In django you can access the queryparameter like the following:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def print_some(request, ):
    variable = request.GET.get('variable', 'default')
    print('Variable:', variable)
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Read more about it here: [HttpRequest.GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)

Comment: Unfortunitley this deosnt seem to work. the result that is printed is "Variable: local" not the local value for some reason.

Comment: I edited my answer. See the  `url:\`printsome/?variable=${local}\``  parameter in ajax call.